# Why will my input form not stick to my button?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Like i say in the title why cant i get the input-form to stick with my button?

I am using bootstrap with my django site.

```
  <div class="container" style="margin-top: 20%; margin-bottom: 20%";>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">     
        <div class="row">
            <div id="logo" class="text-center">
                <h1 style="font-size:500%";>Zaira.io</h1><p style="font-size:120%";>Test</p>
            </div>
            <form role="form" id="form-buscar">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input id="1" class="form-control input-lg" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Input Website Url" required/>
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg" type="submit">
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></i> Search
                            </button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>            
    </div>
</div>
```

[Website Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZq1L.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to create an [input group](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/). If so, then on the line that reads `<span class='input-group-btn'>`, change the class `input-group-btn` to `input-group-append`. Here's [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jennyfofenny/aq9Laaew/285353/) to demonstrate the change.

Comment: This place the button under the search field on my site dont know why it works in fiddle

Comment: Then, it is some issue with the html/css/js for your website. It's hard to pinpoint the issue without more context/code. One way to debug the issue is to inspect the elements and those around them with devtools for any width restrictions. There are other things that could possibly cause issues, as well, like incorrect doctype.

Comment: I used the chome inspect dont know why i did not think about it, found out the site.css file had a max-width on forms. Thansk

Answer (score 0):

Check out this page https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/ to learn more about input group with bootstrap. Also, you should avoid using `span` in this case as it is an inline element and not a block element to position obj. To position, use `input-group-prepend` and/or `input-group-append` as needed for buttons and more.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Input Website Url" aria-label="Input Website Url" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
  <div class="input-group-append">
   <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Search</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
 <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">     
        <div class="row">
            <div id="logo" class="text-center">
                <h1 style="font-size:500%";>Zaira.io</h1>
             
            </div>
            <form role="form" id="form-buscar">
             
                <p style="font-size:120%";>Test</p>
                        <input id="1" class="form-control input-lg" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Input Website Url" required/>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search
    </button>


 
    
   </form>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```